# Making CSS Gradient Expand to Block?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to (sort of) replicate the look of the menu bar at the very top of this theme: http://elegantthemes.com/preview/Lucid/

The part that I'm struggling with is getting the gradient I *borrowed* to take up the entire "block" that an `<li>` element occupies. Since this is a little hard to explain conceptually, here is what I currently have: http://jsfiddle.net/tCH39/

And for reference, here are the relevant pieces of HTML and CSS:

```
  <div id="top-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
body { /* CSS Reset - http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ */
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  border: 0; 
  outline: 0; 
  font-size: 100%; 
  vertical-align: baseline; 
  background: transparent; 
}

ol, ul { list-style: none; }
li {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

a { 
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

#top-menu {
  position: relative;
  /*display: block;*/
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#top-menu a {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff;
  color: #4b4b4b;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#top-menu > ul > li > a { -moz-transition: all .5s; -webkit-transition: all .5s; -o-transition: all .5s; transition: all .5s; }
#top-menu > ul > li > a:hover { color: #fff; background-color: #4b4b4b; text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000; -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.9); -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.9); box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.9); }
#top-menu li.sfHover > a { color: #fff; text-shadow: none; }
```

Why is it that the gradients are constrained just to the text, as opposed to the entire area consisting of padding, margin, etc?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd also advise putting the padding, etc on the `a` so the whole block is clickable, as opposed to just the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you had the gradient on the `a`

```
#top-menu > ul > li > a { -moz-transition: all .5s; -webkit-transition: all .5s; -o-transition: all .5s; transition: all .5s; }
#top-menu > ul > li > a:hover { color: #fff; background-color: #4b4b4b; text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000; -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.9); -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.9); box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.9); }
```

This should be on the `li`.

```
#top-menu > ul > li { -moz-transition: all .5s; -webkit-transition: all .5s; -o-transition: all .5s; transition: all .5s; }
#top-menu > ul > li:hover  { color: #fff; background-color: #4b4b4b; text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000; -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.9); -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.9); box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.9); }
```

Then I increased the height of the `li`.

LI example: http://jsfiddle.net/tCH39/1/

if you want to style the `a` itself.

Do this:

```
ol, ul { list-style: none; padding: 0; margin:0; }


a { 
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    display: block;
}
```

A fiddle showing the a-example: http://jsfiddle.net/tCH39/7/

This is a much cleaner method in my book, since the a is the element you want style and have clickable "all over".

Answer (score 2):

I did certain changes in your CSS. I guess this is what you were looking for.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cbm9u/)

```
ul, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#top-menu {
  position: relative;
  /*display: block;*/
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}
#top-menu ul{
    margin: 0 35px;
}
#top-menu ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left: -4px;
}
#top-menu a {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff;
  color: #4b4b4b;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
    padding: 25px 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are giving styles only to the a tag in li.

Try-

```
#top-menu > ul > li { -moz-transition: all .5s; -webkit-transition: all .5s; -o-transition: all .5s; transition: all .5s; }
#top-menu > ul > li:hover { color: #fff; background-color: #4b4b4b; text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000; -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.9); -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.9); box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.9); }
```

Maybe it helps

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/tCH39/2/

Answer (score 1):

It is only constrained in the text because the `:hover` is link the `<a>` not to the `<li>` tag:

```
#top-menu > ul > li > a:hover { 
color: #fff;
background-color: #4b4b4b;
text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.9); }
```

you can change the css to:

```
#top-menu > ul > li:hover {
color:#fff;
background-color:#4b4b4b;
text-shadow:-1px -1px 0 #000;
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}
```